Saving Fine-tune Falcon HuggingFace LLM Model
I'm trying to save my model so it won't need to re-download the base model every time I want to use it but nothing seems to work for me, I would love your help with it.
The following parameters are used for the training:
hf_model_name = "tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct"
dir_path = 'Tiiuae-falcon-7b-instruct'
model_name_is = f"peft-training"
output_dir = f'{dir_path}/{model_name_is}'
logs_dir = f'{dir_path}/logs'
model_final_path = f"{output_dir}/final_model/"
EPOCHS = 3500
LOGS = 1
SAVES = 700
EVALS = EPOCHS / 100
compute_dtype = getattr(torch, "float16")
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=compute_dtype,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=False,
)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        "tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct",
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        device_map={"": 0},
        trust_remote_code=False
)
peft_config = LoraConfig(
    lora_alpha=16,
    lora_dropout=0.05, # 0.1
    r=64,
    bias="lora_only", # none
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
    target_modules=[
        "query_key_value"
    ],
)
model.config.use_cache = False
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
model.print_trainable_parameters()
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct", trust_remote_code=False)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    optim='paged_adamw_32bit',
    max_steps=EPOCHS,
    save_steps=SAVES,
    logging_steps=LOGS,
    logging_dir=logs_dir,
    eval_steps=EVALS,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    fp16=True,
    learning_rate=0.001,
    max_grad_norm=0.3,
    warmup_ratio=0.15, # 0.03
    lr_scheduler_type="constant",
    disable_tqdm=True,
)
model.config.use_cache = False
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=448,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
    packing=True,
)
for name, module in trainer.model.named_modules():
    if "norm" in name:
        module = module.to(torch.float32)
train_result = trainer.train()

And the saving of it I did like so:
metrics = train_result.metrics
max_train_samples = len(train_dataset)
metrics["train_samples"] = min(max_train_samples, len(train_dataset))
# save train results
trainer.log_metrics("train", metrics)
trainer.save_metrics("train", metrics)
# compute evaluation results
metrics = trainer.evaluate()
max_val_samples = len(eval_dataset)
metrics["eval_samples"] = min(max_val_samples, len(eval_dataset))
# save evaluation results
trainer.log_metrics("eval", metrics)
trainer.save_metrics("eval", metrics)

model.save_pretrained(model_final_path)

Now I've tried so many different ways to load it or load and save it in various ways again and again (for example adding lora_model.merge_and_unload(), plain using local_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(after_merge_model_path) and more), but nothing seems to work for me everything resulted in errors (sometimes the same errors, sometimes different ones), I need your help here.
If you think its better suited, I opened a question here too HuggingFace Forum

What errors are you facing? Normally it should also cache the model locally and download it only once.

I'm looking for a way that wont require it to download it if it's possible, I don't want the platform to get "stuck" for a long time while it downloads and loads it every time the user enters it

The fine-tuning is done by training adapters on top of the base model. And after the training you only save the adapter, not the base model. So the workflow is the following:
During training:

you download the base model from HF and save it in cache directory
you train PEFT adapter and save it

During inferencing

Load cached HF base model
Load saved peft adapter and apply it to the base model

Step 1. Download HF model in predefined cached directory:
import os
from pathlib import Path

# set cache for pretrained model
os.environ['HF_HOME'] = '/content/assets/hf_cache/'
os.environ['HF_DATASETS_CACHE'] = '/content/assets/hf_datasets/'

dir_path = Path('/content')
adapter_final_path = dir_path / f"output" / "final_adapter"
base_quantized_path = dir_path / f"output" / "base_model_q"

hf_model_name = "tiiuae/falcon-7b-instruct"

# load the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hf_model_name, 
                              trust_remote_code=False)
        
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token


# load the model
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=False,
)


model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        hf_model_name,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        device_map={"": 0},
        trust_remote_code=False
)

model.save_pretrained(base_quantized_path)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(base_quantized_path)
...

After the training save peft adapters:
... train the model...

train_result = trainer.train()


model.save_pretrained(adapter_final_path)


During inference reload base model and peft adapter:

# load base model
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(base_quantized_path)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_quantized_path)

# apply saved adapter to the model
model.load_adapter(adapter_final_path)


Is there a way to save the entire model or somehow, so I won't have to redownload the base model each time I want to use it? for example, if I want to integrate it into my Streamlit project, if every time it downloads the base model it will take a lot of time to load

To prevent model from redownloading you need to set HF cache directory os.environ['HF_HOME']. In this case base model will be saved in pre-specified directory and will be loaded from on next call AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained

Another option would be to save pretrained (base) model after loading and quantizing it: model.save_pretrained(base_quantized_path) and tokenizer.save_pretrained(base_quantized_path)

Regarding your second option, how would I do that locally and then upload the model to my Streamlit program so the user won't have to wait until the model downloads?

Hi Lidor, I'm not sure what exactly the problem. Could you please share the full code of the Streamlit app and edit your question with regards to where the problem is. Usually you copy both Streamlit app and the model files to the user. And then on the first launch of Streamlit you preload the model into one of the variables.

Hey, yes I will tonight. but about what you said it's right, the Streamlit app loads the model and downloads the base one. but it takes a lot of time, so I was wondering if there is a way I can save everything on my server with the Streamlit app so the model will be available and it won't need to redownload and reload it?

For example, let's take ChatGPT, when you log into it you don't wait for the model to load, it's there and ready for you the second you go to it

Ok, so then the question then is about how to do this specifically in Streamlit. Because the approach is different depending on frameworks that you use. I would recommend to check this article: https://docs.streamlit.io/develop/concepts/architecture/caching And check example how models are loaded using @st.cache_resource.

I tried using both @st.cache_resource and using os.environ['HF_HOME'] to my D drive, and it still downloads it to my C drive every single time and crashing because of space

Hi Lidor, would help a lot if it is possible to provide an exact Streamlit code that you are using. Thx.

Hi, since that comment I have updated my answer to what I think should be the best option to save/load the model. But again if your answer about the Streamlit I would recommend to post the code that you are using, because Streamlit might require to use some stremlit specific functions for quick saving/loading models.

I've read the code you provided and it seems better, when you save the base model and then load it from the cache directory it will not re-download it and it will be faster? (JohnnyCheesecutter).
What do you think about the answer? @LidorEliyahuShelef

There is several things that you should check: 1) is HF redownloading the model checkpoints from the internet? (turn off wi-fi to check this if you are not sure); 2) Does HF loads the model checkpoint from the files or a memory? At the first call it should load the model from the file and second time it should be called from the memory, otherwise you will create duplicate of the object in the memory and by that might also consume additional GPU memory;


Does Streamlit reloading the model from the file each time you call the app (or when two different users open the app / when you open the app in two different tabs or browsers) or is it using shared object from the memory? Streamlit is build in such way that it reruns all pipelines from scratch for each user. Basically streamlit clones everything from python code for each user.


Thus imho it would benefit to see the exact streamlit code used for loading fine-tuned model.

The problem I have is when streamlit is running and I'm loading the model, it takes too long and takes too much RAM each time so it crashes the app, this is why I wanted to save the actual model locally and load it from there maybe @JohnnyCheesecutter

regardless of streamlit @JohnnyCheesecutter
